# How to change "navbar background color" and "button color"?

Tags: css, button, navigation, background-color

I'm trying to set navbar background color and button color.Where can I set those features color?

I used a css to set those features color , but it can't work.
After compiled , I didn't see any error message.

CSS:

```
.navigation.back{
   background:green;
   font-weight:bold;
```

XPage Code:

```
<xe:navbar id="navbar1" styleClass="navigation.back" headingStyle="font-weight: bold" pageWidth="none">
```

Comment: can you try `<xe:navbar id="navbar1" styleClass="navigation back" headingStyle="font-weight: bold" pageWidth="none">`

Comment: if you have css for navbar mean override with `background: green !important` or just use `back` or `navigation back`

Comment: Try changing `styleClass="navigation.back"` to `styleClass="navigation back"`

Comment: Thanks you all !
I already tried to change `styleClass="navigation.back"` to `styleClass="navigation back"`.But the background color doesn't work.
What other methods can be achieved?
Please give me a hand,Thank you guys!!!!!